# Insert between array in rails .each while loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 100 shoes with shoe names. I don't want to display all 100 in a row, I want to display 5, then a green box, then the next 5, and the same green box... but there is something wrong with my code.

```
<% @shoes.each.with_index(1) do |shoe, index| %>
  <% while index < 101 do %>
    <%= shoe.name %>
    <% if index % 5 == 0 %>
      <%= Green Box %>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `in_groups_of(x)`

```
<% @shoes.in_groups_of(5) do |shoe_groups| %>
    <% shoe_groups.each do |shoe| %>
         <%= shoe.name %>
    <% end %>
    <%= 'Green Box' if shoe_groups.size % 5 == 0 %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: in this case the  `if shoe_groups % 5 == 0 ` isn't needed, since in_groups_of will return 5 shoes, so just need to print out the Green Box code after iterating over the shoes in the group.

Comment: Well, that wouldn't keep to his/her requirements as if the last group only had 4 shoes, you wouldn't display `Green  Box`.

Comment: `in_groups_of` yields an array, array doesn't accept a '%' message, So it will error out., if you remove the if statement, it wil echo the green box after each group (even the last one if it has < 5,).

Comment: @Doon, you are correct. forgot to get the size. Updated. Thank you.

Comment: Should be @shoes.in_groups_of(5, false) . It pads remaining slots with nil, so the code will call nil.name whenever it divides the group by 5 and gets a remainder. http://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups_of

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong in several places - the enumerator is wrong, you are missing several `end` statements.  Also, even though `index` is not a reserved word, the generally accepted style for an index is a single-letter variable like `i`.  It should be

```
<% @shoes.each_with_index(1) do |shoe, i| %>
  <% while i < 101 do %>
    <%= shoe.name %>
    <% if i % 5 == 0 %>
      <%= Green Box %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

(But personally, I would not do the index < 101 block in the view - I would make sure that the controller that generates @shoes and sends it to the view only sends 100 elements in the array)

Comment: the inner while loop here is not needed and will cause an infinite loop. , the outer `each_with_index` will iterate over the loop just fine. and each_with_index doesn't take an argument